# Chrome Web Workers Stop Running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timer, settimeout, web-worker

I am running a setTimeout timer to update our JWT token. Most of the time it works fine, but it appears Chrome is throttling the setTimeout. After doing some research I changed it to use [hacktimer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hacktimer) and moved it to a Web Worker, which appears to be slightly more reliable, but still causes the setTimeout to stop for a period of 30 minutes, causing the token to be invalid. And yes, I verified that hacktimer is working. Is there another solution to dealing with the throttling on Chrome based browsers?

Comment: I think browsers are always going to try and save on power usage, and throttling timeouts is of course a common option.  That hacktimer hasn't been updated for over 6 years, and there has been substantial updates on how timeouts throttle since then.  Out of curiosity if you place a timer that makes a beep or some noise every few minutes, does this fix it, as media playback is one of the keep-alive tactics.  Another idea, if you run your website in WebApp mode does it work better.?

Comment: How are you playing Audio?,  you are using the `<Audio/>` tag, and not the `<Video/>`, because the error doesn't make sense if it's audio.. I've knocked up a snippet for an answer using audio tag, it seems to work but I've not done any extended testing, maybe 10 mins, hopefully it keeps thing going longer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a snippet that plays audio constantly in a loop, click the play button and it starts an interval that counts, this is compared to how many seconds have ellapsed, I tested going to other tabs its seems to keep the interval & time in sync, so it doesn't seem to throttle it.  I waited a fair amount of time, not 30 mins, maybe give this a try.

```js
const qs = s => document.querySelector(s);

const btn = qs("button");
const audio = qs("audio");
const timeoutTicks = qs('#timeoutTicks');
const fromStart = qs("#fromStart");

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.play();
  let counter = 0;
  const started = Date.now();
  setInterval(() => {
     timeoutTicks.innerText = ++counter;
     fromStart.innerText = Math.round((Date.now() - started)/1000);
  }, 1000); 
});
```

```css
.tick {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="tick">
  <span>Set Timeout Ticks</span>
  <span id="timeoutTicks">0</span>
  <span>Seconds from start</span>
  <span id="fromStart">0</span>  
  <button>start</button>
</div>

<audio
  paused
   loop
   controls
   src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Lorem_ipsum.ogg"/>
```