# How to prevent different browsers from freezing its idle tabs?

Tags: javascript, angular, page-lifecycle

I am trying to create a session timeout functionality where if the user stays idle for a certain period of time (say `session_timeout`, a pop up should be displayed on the UI and if still not acted upon then logout automatically.

It works fine if the `session_timeout<=20 minutes`(approx). But it doesn't work if `session_timeout>40 minutes`. I don't see any pop up and the user is not logged out either.

My guess is after a certain period of inactivity, the browser freezes its idle tabs thus the timer which was supposed to countdown the `session_timeout` also stops updating.

Is this a good guess? If yes, how do I prevent the browser from freezing my tab? Are there any other possible reasons why this could be happening?

And what is the best way to implement this functionality?

Please note that I've implemented this in Angular and Javascript.

Comment: How exactly have you implemented the check. Please provide a snippet fo your implementation.

Comment: Usually we handle the session from backend, check if this helps you. https://medium.com/tinyso/how-to-detect-inactive-user-to-auto-logout-by-using-idle-timeout-in-javascript-react-angular-and-b6279663acf2

Comment: Your likely hitting `setTimeout` throttling, I did talk about this with another user, I think the easiest solution was playing audio in a loop  (I know, it seems like a hack). ;),  link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096458/chrome-web-workers-stop-running/76105027#76105027

Comment: @Keith - not just a hack, but hostile to battery life?   If a user will be logged out after 40 minutes and the tab is inactive for an hour, why not just show a "you were logged out" alert after they come back to the tab and try to do something?  Update some "last activity" state and check for a >x minute gap before allowing new activity?  (Also, hacks like playing silent music will probably be caught by Google, etc. eventually and blocked.)

Comment: @DaveS  Yeah, there is a good reason Google are doing it.  I'm not advocating it, just pointing out it's the only way I know of stopping timeouts getting throttled.  There is maybe a good reason for the OP wanting this, so I'm not going to judge if it's wrong or right in the OP's case, that's for him to decide.  I might be wrong, but I think the silent music options might already be getting blocked, I remember reading something about it somewhere.  And yes, is the reason I flagged it a hack.. !!! :)

Comment: @DaveS /Keith, Are **Web Workers** a solution to this? Or do web workers also get throttled after some inactivity?

Comment: Google is cracking down on everything in the non-foreground tabs to improve battery life, performance in the active tab, and (to a lesser extent) hinder scams like mining.

Comment: @aabidm  This was one option I initially mentioned, there is even a package that uses webWorkers to replace built-in, https://github.com/chrisguttandin/worker-timers  But from what I can gather this option didn't seem to work, and like Dave mentions above Google just seem to be cracking down on any background tasks, so even if it did work, there is a good chance it will stop in the future.  What would be nice is the ability for a webpage to request background permissions, like been able to request camera access etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I solved this issue by simply reducing the timeout configuration to 5 minutes. I guess it doesn't make much sense to allow a user to be away from the computer for 30 minutes and then logout. Thanks for all the suggestions.